# Layer text over an image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to lay text over an image.  I set the z-index on the div, but that doesn't do anything until I set the position to absolute.

```
<script>
function SwitchActiveDiv() {
    $("#SummaryDiv").css('display', 'none');
    $("#DetailsDiv").css('display', 'inline');
}
function SwapOpenImage(img) {
    var ToImage = $(img).attr('src').substring($(img).attr('src').lastIndexOf('/'));
    ToImage = ToImage.replace('closed', 'open');

    var FromImage = $("#OpenImage").attr('src').substring($(img).attr('src').lastIndexOf('/'));
    FromImage = FromImage.replace('open', 'closed');

    var OpenImageSrc = $("#OpenImage").attr('src');
    OpenImageSrc = OpenImageSrc.substring(0, OpenImageSrc.lastIndexOf('/')) + ToImage;

    var CloseImageSrc = $(img).attr('src');
    CloseImageSrc = CloseImageSrc.substring(0, CloseImageSrc.lastIndexOf('/')) + FromImage;

    $("#OpenImage").attr('src', OpenImageSrc);
    $(img).attr('src', CloseImageSrc);
}
</script>
<div id="SummaryDiv" style="width: 100%;">
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width: 712px;">
    <img src="~/media/C2MAssets/GettingStartedIntro/change-image.jpg" alt="" onclick="javascript:SwitchActiveDiv();" />
</td>
<td style="padding-left: 3px;">
    <img src="~/media/C2MAssets/GettingStartedIntro/family-image.jpg" alt="" onclick="javascript:SwitchActiveDiv();" />
</td>
<td style="padding-left: 3px;">
    <img src="~/media/C2MAssets/GettingStartedIntro/lifestyle-image.jpg" alt="" onclick="javascript:SwitchActiveDiv();" />
</td>
<td style="padding-left: 3px;">
    <img src="~/media/C2MAssets/GettingStartedIntro/play-image.jpg" alt="" onclick="javascript:SwitchActiveDiv();" />
</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
<div id="DetailsDiv" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
<table>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">
    <img id="OpenImage" src="~/media/C2MAssets/GettingStartedDetails/change-open.jpg" alt="" />
    <div style="z-index: 20; left: 800px; top: 330px; position: relative;">
        <p style="font-family: Helvetica Neue; font-size: 35px; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff;">Ready for an<br/> <i>Upgrade?</i></p>
    </div>
</td>
<td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <img id="ClosedImage1" src="~/media/C2MAssets/GettingStartedDetails/family-closed.jpg" alt="" onclick="javascript:SwapOpenImage(this);" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <img id="ClosedImage2" src="~/media/C2MAssets/GettingStartedDetails/lifestyle-closed.jpg" alt="" onclick="javascript:SwapOpenImage(this);" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <img id="ClosedImage3" src="~/media/C2MAssets/GettingStartedDetails/play-closed.jpg" alt="" onclick="javascript:SwapOpenImage(this);" />
</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
```

Then when I set the position, it sort of works.  Initially, the top div is not visible and then jquery enables it.  When the top div is enambled, the text div is still not visible and doesn't become visible until some jquery is activated to replace the image that the text should be over, then it becomes visible.

Comment: Please post the relevant CSS, and jQuery code as well.

Comment: Are you talking about doing something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2PJMd/

Comment: I added the rest of the code on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container needs to be positioned relative and the div with the text in it needs to be absolute.

Try this:

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Placeholding text</td>
        <td>Another placeholder</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Image next to me</td>
        <td class="img-container">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
            <span class="overlay-text">
                Text goes here
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.img-container
{
    position: relative;
}

.overlay-text
{
    font-family: Arial;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px white;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: none;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVyJE/3/) for it.

Comment: Here is one with jQuery to show and hide the overlay: http://jsfiddle.net/2PJMd/1/

Comment: @JasonSperske Edited it into the fiddle.